# Output from webscraped page not appended to output from previous page

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

Similar to my last question, I'm having an iteration issue. I'm using the code

`df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Username': [name.text for name in (soup.findAll('p',{'class':'profile-name'}))]})`

to get the list of names from one web page. However, when I try this for all pages, it creates new tables for each page instead of appending the output from each page together.

So for page 1 I'd get

```
       Username
 0     Alice
 1     Bob
 2     Carl
```

Page 2 :

```
       Username
 0     Sandra
 1     Paula
 2     Tim
```

etc. But I want my output to be:

```
       Username
 0     Alice
 1     Bob
 2     Car
 3     Sandra
 4     Paula
 5     Tim
```

Below is my full code (with the url omitted) for iterating through all the pages

```
for pageno in range(0,99):
    page=requests.get('full url'+ str(pageno))
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Username': [name.text for name in (soup.findAll('p',{'class':'profile-name'}))]})
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your issue is that you are creating a new `df` at each loop so previous pages' records are not kept.

You might want to append your usernames to a global list and then import that list in a dataframe:

```
  username_list = []
  for pageno in range(0,99):
      page=requests.get('full url'+ str(pageno))
      soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
      username_list += [name.text for name in (soup.findAll('p',{'class':'profile-name'}))]

  df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Username':  username_list})
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty unclear, but I guess this is what you wanted?

```
output_df = pd.DataFrame()
for pageno in range(0,99):
    page=requests.get('full url'+ str(pageno))
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Username': [name.text for name in (soup.findAll('p',{'class':'profile-name'}))]})
    output_df = pd.concat([output_df, df1])
```